# Why NextJs isn't generating this file on heroku?

Tags: pdf, heroku, next.js, puppeteer

I'm using NextJs hosted on Heroku and the project running localhost generates a pdf file inside the public folder but doesn't happen on Heroku.

Does this have something with Heroku ephemeral storage? I hope not because the project just needs to generate the pdf to user download it, and then it can be deleted.

I'm using puppeteer to generate the pdf and the code is basically:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: true,
  defaultViewport: null,
  args: ['--incognito', '--no-sandbox', '--single-process', '--no-zygote'],
});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setContent('content-goes-here');
await page.emulateMediaType('screen');

await page.pdf({
  path: 'public/file.pdf',
  format: 'A4',
  printBackground: true,
});
await browser.close();
```

This works on localhost but doesn't generate the file on Heroku and I don't know the reason.

Comment: Check your Heroku logs to see if you get any errors when this happens?

Comment: I got a "/app/node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-856583/chrome-linux/chrome: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: Consider clearing the cache and running the build again on Heroku. See [Github Issue](https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack/issues/14#issuecomment-420787705)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have Heroku Buildpack for Puppeteer installed

You can do it from the terminal by running the following commands accordingly

```js
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

You can do it via your Heroku Dashboard

Open the Heroku app, go to Settings > Buildpacks > Add buildpack and add the URL

`https://github.com/jontewks/puppeteer-heroku-buildpack`

Comment: That worked! But I made a mistake since nextJS doesn't load dynamic assets.